# Running actions in another directory

Tags: github, github-actions

I've just started exploring Github actions however I've found myself placing a command in multiple places.

I have a PHP project where the `composer.json` is not in the root, my structure looks like:

```
my-project:
    readme.md
    app:
        composer.json
```

Obviously there is more to it and there is a reason why, but my `composer.json` sits in a subdirectory called 'app'. As a result in my workflow, I have to cd into that folder every time to run a command:

```
name: CI

on: [push]

jobs:
  phpunit:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: Setup Symfony
        run: |
          cd app
          cp .env.dev .env
      - name: Install Composer Dependencies
        run: |
          cd app
          composer install --prefer-dist
      - name: Run Tests
        run: |
          cd app
          php bin/phpunit
```

How can I remove the `cd app` in every stage?

Answer (score 435, accepted):

**Update**: It's now possible to set a `working-directory` default for a job. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63122434/11934042).

There is an option to set a `working-directory` on a step, but not for multiple steps or a whole job. I'm fairly sure this option only works for script steps, not action steps with `uses`.

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsrun

Using `working-directory`, your workflow would look like this. It's still quite verbose but maybe a bit cleaner.

```
name: CI

on: [push]

jobs:
  phpunit:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: Setup Symfony
        working-directory: ./app
        run: cp .env.dev .env
      - name: Install Composer Dependencies
        working-directory: ./app
        run: composer install --prefer-dist
      - name: Run Tests
        working-directory: ./app
        run: php bin/phpunit
```

Alternatively, you can run it all in one step so that you only need to specify `working-directory` once.

```
name: CI

on: [push]

jobs:
  phpunit:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: Setup and run tests
        working-directory: ./app
        run: |
          cp .env.dev .env
          composer install --prefer-dist
          php bin/phpunit
```

Comment: Is it possible to set different `working-directory` for different steps?

Comment: @idkman yes, you can add working-directory: ./app to every step. Thats exactly what this answer is about :)

Comment: if you are using `uses` such as  the UploadArtifact action. what is the solution for this edgecase?

Answer (score 338):

You can now add a default working directory for all steps in a job: [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_iddefaultsrun)

For the example here, this would be:

```
name: CI

on: [push]

jobs:
  phpunit:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: ./app
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: Setup Symfony
        run: .env.dev .env
      - name: Install Composer Dependencies
        run: composer install --prefer-dist
      - name: Run Tests
        run: php bin/phpunit
```

Caveat: this only applies to `run` steps; eg you'll still need to add the subdirectory to `with` parameters of `uses` steps, if required.

Comment: Do you know how to use `working-directory` with `uses`? As you mentioned, do you have any example using `with` and `uses`? Thanks

Comment: Which action do you `uses` and does it have any arguments (specified with `with`) that need given a path? If so, these paths must be given relative to the default root dir, and not the `default.run.working-directory`.

Comment: @theprogrammer if you use `uses` the author of the package has to specifically support `working-directory` or implement something similar for their purpose and context. As far as I have seen, most dont.

Comment: Can we use variable in working-directory eg ./app/$SOME_DIR?

Comment: For the FirebaseHosting push, you can add to `with:` following field `entryPoint: "./someDirectory`

Answer (score 96):

Hope this will help somebody

```
name: CI

on:
 ...

defaults:
 run:
  working-directory: ./app

jobs:
 ...
```

Comment: thank you, you saved my day because previous answers didn't work for me

Comment: This helped me tremendously with a weird problem.