# "npm install" in Github Actions failed

Tags: npm, continuous-integration, create-react-app, github-actions

I tried to create a github action that operates on *./example* folder. Code that is inside */.example* folder was built by using *create-react-app*.

Workflow code:

```
name: CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ origin ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ origin ]

jobs:
  build_test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [10.x, 15.x]

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      - name: npm install, build, and test example
        working-directory: example
        run: |
          npm install
          npm run build --if-present
```

But it causes an error:
[image]

The structure of my project (inside *./example* there is *package.json*):

[image]

Comment: Could you share your project (if it is public) to test the workflow on a fork?

Comment: You might be able to find an answer here: [running-actions-in-another-directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58139175/running-actions-in-another-directory)

Answer (score 0):

Your workflow yaml file should look like below.

```
name: CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ origin ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ origin ]

jobs:
  build_test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [10.x, 15.x]
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      - name: npm install, build, and test example
        working-directory: ./example
        run: |
          npm install
          npm run build --if-present
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work: `npm ERR! Could not install from "../node_modules/@types/node" as it does not contain a package.json file.`

Comment: Are you installing any local dependancy ? Because I feel this is not because NPM didn't find package.json. please find below link for reference https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/18266. If NPM didn't find your `package.json` it would have thrown below error, `no such file or directory, open '/example/package.json'`

Comment: working-directory tag supported in v2 version?